# Does spring security use AOP internally?

Tags: spring, spring-security, aop, spring-aop

I hear that AOP can be used for separating cross cutting aspects like security, transaction and logging etc.
So, I want to understand that if spring security internally uses AOP ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Spring Security uses AOP internally. For example, it is used for global method security. Global method security is used to apply security checks to certain methods (for example, in service layer).

You can find the following code in `GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser` that is a part of Spring Security infrastructure relating to global method security:

```
    if (useAspectJ) {
        BeanDefinitionBuilder aspect =
            BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition("org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aspectj.aspect.AnnotationSecurityAspect");
        aspect.setFactoryMethod("aspectOf");
        aspect.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
        aspect.addPropertyValue("securityInterceptor", interceptor);
        String id = pc.getReaderContext().registerWithGeneratedName(aspect.getBeanDefinition());
        pc.registerBeanComponent(new BeanComponentDefinition(aspect.getBeanDefinition(), id));
    } else {
        registerAdvisor(pc, interceptor, metadataSource, source, element.getAttribute(ATT_ADVICE_ORDER));
        AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(pc, element);
    }
```

It mentions AOP almost in every line.

More information on global method security may be found, for example, here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html and here https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/

Comment: gr8.  so is this run time weaving or compile time?

Comment: Proxy-based AOP is runtime. With AspectJ, I'm not that sure, that I'd suggest that it uses run time weaving as otherwise it would not be possible to reconfigure a Spring application by simply changing XML (and no recompilation).